# Nginx Reverse Proxy Basic Auth Base64 Url Encode

Tags: nginx, base64, reverse-proxy

I'm using a **reverse proxy** in front of a web application I do **not** have a hand on.

To connect my user automatically, I use **Basic Auth**. So I pass an argument in base 64 in the url like this http://mysiteweb/monurl?User=credentialsBase64Encoded

Unfortunately, the web application behind my url proxy encodes my query string parameter. So the authentication is not good when my proxy passes it in the header.

Here is my Nginx configuration.

```
server {
    listen    80;
    root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    index index.html index.htm;
    server_name mydomain.com;

    location /mywebapp/ {

        set $basicAuth "Basic $arg_user";
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3524/;
        proxy_set_header Authorization $basicAuth;
    }
}
```

How can I fix the problem without having access to the web application behind the proxy?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: 0

If I understand your question right you making the basic auth over nginx and you dont want to receive the query params on your web application? Than you can simply remove it in the nginx conf:

`if ($query_string ~ "^(.*)User=(.*)$") {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ $uri? permanent;
}`

Comment: No my proxy is used to transform my query string parameter in header. Authentication is done by the web application behind. Thus the query string parameter must be kept but it must not be url encode. Or I have to find another way to pass it

Comment: Ah okay I understand. You can simply pass it as header and decode the b64 string in the web application. I would recommend passing the string encoded around. I don't know which language you are using but normally you can (d)e[n]code a bas64 string in one line

Comment: The problem is that it's not my web application. I do not have the hand on it: /

Comment: You can write an application that proxies the request. Instead of Nginx, there is not really a good way to add this (business logic) functionality to nginx. You can also take a look if you want to use Zuul or a API Gateway and add the logic to it

Comment: I agree with you but is it possible to do it with nginx temporarily (the time I put up the proxy app) ?